# Static Library Red

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

I downloaded the PaperFoldMenuController from CocoaControls.

When I open it up it doesn't seem to have the PaperFold library included.

Is this something to do with static libraries? Am I supposed to go look for this library and then copy it in? I'm not really sure how these libraries are supposed to work.

Thanks,

Alan

[image]

Comment: If they are available in folder the project is, then remove all `RED` colored files and then add them to project again :)

Comment: They're not there! There's just an empty folder where they should be. I found it separately on git hub but it seems to be missing files that this project needs...

Comment: For example, the PaperFold library doesn't have the ShadowView files that you can see are in red in the above screen shot

Comment: Then there is no way to do any thing with them as they are missing.

Comment: May the author have includes files to project without copping them to the project :)

Comment: Yep It's the problem in the git repository posted by author :) We can't do any thing until the author updates the repository :)

Comment: You should also note that the files listed in red are **source** files and not a "static library".  They may be used to **build** a static library but that would be a different thing entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The PaperFold library is a git submodule of that library. You either have to use git to pull the submodule manually, or use a git client that can do that for you. I use SourceTree. It pulls all the submodules automatically. You'll have all the files with you.